# Android expandablelistview GroupView doesn't show selection onClick if other above GroupView is expand

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have ExpandableListView with 4 groups. If group at position 0 is expanded then when I click on group at position 1, the selection (red color) of that group doesn't show. If I expand group at position 3 and then at position 2, everything is okay and selection shows up. I have 4 listeners, which listens to group selected, expanded, collapsed and child pressed. On selected, expanded and collapsed listeners displayView() method is called. Then according to position method should select group and either show new Fragment either not. I know that the method gets the right position and should select. What's wrong?

My list listeners:

```
mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, long id) {
        displayView(groupPosition);
        return false;
    }
});

mDrawerList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        displayView(groupPosition);    
    }
});

mDrawerList.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
        displayView(groupPosition);    
    }
});

mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

My displayView method:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new Eat();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new About();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
    //here method have a right position of a group
    if (fragment != null) {
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}
```